# Flash button stuck after popup or alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash, popup

I am facing this problem since 5 months now, so I'm asking here on SO.

I've implemented a **simple flash button**.

- The button displays an **animation on mouse-over**.
- When the button is clicked, it calls an external JS library of mine.  The libray
  **displays a popup**, or sometimes a javascript alert.

Now, the problem is that when the button is clicked (and the popup/alert is displayed), **the button gets stuck at the last frame of the animation**, and it never goes back to the first frame.

I've tried with many combinations:

- I coded the button with AS3 listeners (putting a mouseout listener).
- I used the standard flash button.

Nothing, it always gets stuck, as if the flash component can't detect the mouse movement after the opening of the popup.

You can check the behaviour I'm talking about just following [this link](http://2outof0studio.com/SWift/SWift.php?Lang=IT&Mode=Single) and clicking on any of the animated button (the top-left recycle bin button, for example).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what the last frame of the recycle button is? I can't workout if I am seeing the same as you as I don't know the frames of that clip, can I get to the code anywhere?

Comment: @Neil Hi!, you can find the full .fla file here (i saved it in Flash CS4 format) [link](http://2outof0studio.com/Upload/StackExchange/Clear.fla) and a Screenshot of the last frame here [link](http://2outof0studio.com/Upload/StackExchange/ClearSS.png), tell me if you need more! =)

Comment: I am not seeing the issue. When I click on any of the animated buttons and then dismiss the pop up they animate again like they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not fire the mouseout event manually before calling the popup? alternatively try to reset the animation when calling the popup.

```
$('#recycle_bin').click(function(){
$(this).mouseout();
call popup;
});
```

would be a jQuery raw code i would try.

Comment: Hey! nice one, I'll give it a try this afternoon!

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the button state on **both** the mouse out event ***and*** the click event.

In Firefox (I only observed the behavior in Firefox) it seems like the pop-up background HTML element is "stealing" the mouse events, which means the mouse out event is never triggered which is why resetting the button state on click should resolve the issue.